# Vue.Js comparing string failed

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to vue.js. I've tried this way to compare two strings, but it seems to fail in vue. How can I solve this issue?

I've tried this:

`app.vue`

```
@Component
export default class Game extends Vue{
  public word = ""
  public words: Array<string> = ["hello", "world"]

  public checkValue(): void{
    const firstWord = this.words.shift();
    if(firstWord === this.word){  // this condition is failing
      console.log("Success")
    }
  }
}
```

`app.html`

```
<md-input v-on:keyup.space="checkValue()" v-model="word"></md-input>
```

Why this condition is failing?

Comment: firstWord still array

Answer (score 3):

Because you have an event keyup with space so word always have a space at end. Please trim before compare.

```js
@Component
export default class Game extends Vue{
  public word = ""
  public words: Array<string> = ["hello", "world"]

  public checkValue(): void{
    const firstWord = this.words.shift();
    if(firstWord === this.word.trim()) {
      console.log("Success")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the below block of code, it should solve your issue

```
  if (firstWord === this.word.trim()) {
      // to do
      console.log("Success");
    }
```

actually `this.word` always containing a space with your given word into input box. thats why it will never match. so you have to trim the given input word.

you can check the [result](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-field-1gmsu?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Hi, I've tested my string with `console.log(typeof firstWord)` and it shows `string`. How can I solve that?

Comment: This is my codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-goldstine-bm6ez?file=/src/App.vue